# when using tabularx and X, how to make the text vertically centered?

Tags: vertical-alignment, tabularx

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[landscape,hmargin=2cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.6cm,headsep=1mm,headheight=3cm]  {geometry} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|*{7}{c|}X|*{5}{c|}p{35mm}|}
    \hline
    &&&&suface quality&&&The financials crashed and burned during the 2008 meltdown but have since been in recovery mode with the rest of the market. This article will explore the risks and rewards associated with these Financial ETFs to identify which have been the best performers.&check&\SI{100}{\percent}&continueous&&worker& The Best Financial ETFs \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}  
\end{document}
```

[image]
As the above code show,the text can't in the center vertically,how to improve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your preamble to make text vertically centered with `X` column

```
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
```

Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[landscape,hmargin=2cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.6cm,headsep=1mm,headheight=3cm]  {geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|*{7}{c|}X|*{5}{c|}p{35mm}|}
    \hline
    &&&&suface quality&&&The financials crashed and burned during the 2008 meltdown but have since been in recovery mode with the rest of the market. This article will explore the risks and rewards associated with these Financial ETFs to identify which have been the best performers.&check&\SI{100}{\percent}&continueous&&worker& The Best Financial ETFs \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]